# Mapping a Dataframe into another using conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to map one dataframe into another, though it is not so simple because I am using 2 conditions to execute the mapping - I will explain them below. Basically, what I am trying to do is given two dataframes, df1 and df2, such that:

df1:

```
A       B        Type
Heart   Spades   Boo
Heart   Clubs    Fog
Spades  Diamonds Bler
```

df2:

```
A       B        Boo    Fog     Bler
Heart   Spades   True   True    True
Spades  Diamonds True   False   True
Heart   Spades   True   True    False
```

I could map the values contained in the columns 'Boo','Fog,'Bler' into a new column in df1 called 'Verification', resulting in:

```
A       B           Type    Verification
Heart   Spades      Boo     True
Heart   Clubs       Fog 
Spades  Diamonds    Bler    True
```

Then, to do this process I have 2 conditions that need to be filled: the values in df1 and the values in df2 for the columns A and B must be equal - as they were acting as keys, and the mapping should take the values in some column of df2 based on the value in the type of df1. I am having two difficulties:

1. The mapping requires two columns so I am not able to figure out a way to use pandas.series.map; furthermore I was not able to apply Dataframe.loc[conditions] in this context so that the conditions compare df1 and df2.
2. The example above is quite short, but the data set that I am working on has several combinations from the values of A and B, hence is unreasonable to write a function of association between A,B and value to each type.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `melt` and `drop_duplicates` on `df2`. Finally, left `merge` df1 to the result of `melt` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df_final = (df1.merge(df2.melt(['A','B'], var_name='Type', value_name='Verification')
                         .drop_duplicates(['A','B','Type']), how='left'))

Out[240]:
        A         B  Type Verification
0   Heart    Spades   Boo         True
1   Heart     Clubs   Fog          NaN
2  Spades  Diamonds  Bler         True
```

---

**Note**: on `df2`, the value of `bler` for `Spades  Diamonds` (2nd row) is `True`, so its `Verification` is `True` in the output

Comment: Hi Andy, it works! I've edited the post with your note, thanks

Answer (score 0):

duckdb：

```
df1.sql().join(df2.sql().select("a a2,b b2,Boo,Fog,Bler"),condition="a=a2 and b=b2",how="left")\
    .aggregate("a,b,type,first(case when type='Boo' then Boo when type='Bler' then Bler when type='Fog' then Fog end) Verification")

：

┌─────────┬──────────┬─────────┬──────────────┐
│    A    │    B     │  Type   │ Verification │
│ varchar │ varchar  │ varchar │   boolean    │
├─────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────────┤
│ Spades  │ Diamonds │ Bler    │ true         │
│ Heart   │ Clubs    │ Fog     │ NULL         │
│ Heart   │ Spades   │ Boo     │ true         │
└─────────┴──────────┴─────────┴──────────────┘
```